# How I can search inside the json that is consisted of an array of a JSON into objects?

Tags: postgresql

Ι have the following table named `discounts`:

```
id Serialize
discount INT
offers JSON
```

With the following records

| id | discount | offers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | [{"type":"discount","percent":100},{"type":"freebie","id:100}] |
| 2 | 0 | [{"type":"discount","percent":100},{"type":"freebie","id:100}] |
| 2 | 100 | NULL |

How I can search inside the table for all records that have non zero discount but inside the JSON that has type `discount` inside the JSON.

So far I have tried this query:

```
select * 
from discounts r 
where discount <> 0 
  and offers @> '[{"type":"discount"}]'::json;
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: json @> json
>
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>
> Position: 68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE discounts (id INT, discount INT, offers JSON);
> INSERT INTO discounts VALUES
> (1,   10, '[{"type":"discount","percent":100},{"type":"freebie","id":100}]'::JSON),
> (2,   0,  '[{"type":"discount","percent":100},{"type":"freebie","id":100}]'::JSON),
> (2,   100,    NULL);
> SELECT * FROM discounts;
> ```
>
> | id | discount | offers |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 10 | [{"type":"discount","percent":100},{"type":"freebie","id":100}] |
> | 2 | 0 | [{"type":"discount","percent":100},{"type":"freebie","id":100}] |
> | 2 | 100 | *null* |

> ```
> select * 
> from discounts r 
> where discount <> 0 
>   and offers @> '[{"type":"discount"}]'::json;
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @> json
> LINE 4:   and offers @> '[{"type":"discount"}]'::json;
>                      ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

> ```
> select * 
> from discounts r 
> where discount <> 0 
>   and offers::JSONB @> '[{"type":"discount"}]'::JSONB;
> ```
>
> | id | discount | offers |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 10 | [{"type":"discount","percent":100},{"type":"freebie","id":100}] |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f68db2c02c5e359a3189a7352ba097b8)*